# Какое значение возвратит функция, если матрица задана следующим образом?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int matr2(int **Y, int n, int m){
int max,i,j,k=0,d;
max = Y[0][0];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
if (Y[j][i]>max) {max = Y[j][i]; k=i;}
d=0;
printf("%d\n",k);
for(i=0;i<n;i++) d+= Y[i][k];
return d; }
```

мой вариант решения

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
void matr2(int **Y, int n, int m){
 
int max,i,j,k=0,d;
max = Y[0][0];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
if (Y[j][i]>max) {max = Y[j][i]; k=i;}
d=0;
printf("%d\n",k);
for(i=0;i<n;i++) d+= Y[i][k];
std::cout<< d; }
int main()
{
    int Y[6][5]= {4,6,9,4,2,6,6,0,3,9,7,4,9,4,4,7,7,2,7,4,1,2,7,7,1,0,3,1,1,7};
    cout << matr2();
}
```

после компеляции молчит, а должно возвращать сумму ряда, в котором обнаружен максимальный элемент матрицы как я понял

Comment: Вы серьезно ждете, что функция, объявленная как `void matr2(...`, что-то вернет?...

Comment: ```void matr2() => cout << matr2()``` **void**

Comment: cout << matr2(здесь нужно что то указать?)

Comment: matr2(Y, 30) так ??

Comment: Кстати, оно у вас что, и правда "скомпелировалось"? 8-/

Comment: ошибку показывало, потом заново запустил ошибку не показывало, но был черный экран и мегало в углу белый квадрат как когда нужно вводить что то

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int matr2(int Y[][5], int rows)
{
    int max = Y[0][0], maxrow = 0, maxsum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            sum += Y[i][j];
            if (Y[i][j] > max)  // Так - первая строка с максимальным элементом
            if (Y[i][j] >= max) // Так - последняя строка с максимальным элементом
            {
                max = Y[i][j];
                maxrow = i;
            }
        }
        if (maxrow == i) maxsum = sum;
    }
    return maxsum;
}
int main()
{
    int Y[6][5]= {4,6,9,4,2,6,6,0,3,9,7,4,9,4,4,7,7,2,7,4,1,2,7,7,1,0,3,1,1,7};
    cout << matr2(Y,6);
}
```

Comment: что то я вообще запутался вроде ответ не верный выходит

Comment: См. https://ideone.com/grplEO Выводит 25. Максимальный элемент 9. Сумма значений в первой строке, где он находится, 25. Это значение и выводится. **ЧТО** не так?

Comment: https://ibb.co/2MKkph4

Comment: Что вы спросили? *должно возвращать сумму ряда, в котором обнаружен максимальный элемент матрицы* Я такой код написал. В задании вопрос совсем иной — что вернет приведенный код. У вас ваш вопрос не соответствует вопросу из задания. В задании выводится на экран номер **первого столбца** с максимальным элементом, и возвращается сумма элементов этого **столбца**. Т.е. функция на экран выведет 2, а вернет 28. Если вас интересует, почем яблоки, не спрашивайте, как продавать груши :)

Comment: понятно, я значит непонял суть кода